# How do I bind a LINQ query to the row of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I need to bind a LINQ query to the row of a gridview. I'm trying to create a table like the matrix in expedia where there are nonstop, 1 stop and 2 stops on different rows. I'm not quite sure how to bind the queries to the gridview rows. I appreciate your help.

```
    var imgquery = from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata3.xml")).Elements("flight")
                   orderby Convert.ToInt32(f.Element("price").Value)
                   select new
                   {
                       ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineimageurl").Value
                   };


    //query for gvMatrix where numberofstops=0
    var numstops0query = from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata3.xml")).Elements("flight")
                where Convert.ToInt32(f.Element("numberofstops").Value) == 0
                orderby Convert.ToInt32(f.Element("price").Value)
                select new
                {
                    Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price"),
                    ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineimageurl").Value
                };

    <asp:GridView ID="gvMatrix" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: do you mean that every rows is going to bind with different dataset ?

Comment: Please provide some code sample on what you're trying to do

Comment: i mean that each row will bind to a different query. does this make sense? each row would have a different where condition, like where nonstop=0, nonstop=1, nonstop=2

Comment: please put up some code so that we can help you.

Comment: i added my code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to call your secondary query from the GridView RowDataBound event and then manually populate your secondary value fields:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

However, it seems that you might be able to get what you are looking for in a SQL join or sub-select. If you are using a SQL data source, I would play around with SQL to see if I could get the data in a single Select statement, then go back and see if I can translate the SQL query into appropriate LINQ -- or I might call it via a stored procedure. However, if you are committed to LINQ, or if a join or sub-select will not do, then RowDataBound is your best bet.

Comment: Hi, I'm thinking of using the RowDataBound. I went to that link, but still am not sure how to bind the LINQ query to the RowDataBound event

Comment: You really cannot "bind" the query.  You manually execute it and place the values into the grid row.  When the RowDataboundEvent is triggered for each row, you will need to get the row values you need to identify the current row/parameters, and then execute the LINQ query to retrieve the row-specific results.  Finally, you use the syntax shown (e.Rows.Cells) to place the results in the appropriate columns.  Here's a more in-depth example.  It is not doing a query for each row, but it shows other manipulations.  http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/take-row-level-control-of-your-gridview/

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that, Grid View will give you the desired functionality because the dataset will bind to whole grid. You can create HTMl table structure at runtime and on every row you create you have control over it to bind whatever linq data that you have. hope it helps :)

```
placeHolder.Controls.Clear(); //asp:placeholder holds the table structure.
Table table = new Table();
table.ID = "table";
placeHolder.Controls.Add(table); //adding to place holder

TableRow row = new TableRow();
row.ID ="rowID";
table.Rows.Add(row); //creating first row for first linq dataset

var nonstop0query = from x in obj select new {x.ID, x.Name, x.Age}; //first linq dataset.

//Creating cells for the data returned by the nonstop0query
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.ID = "cell1";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
cell.Text = nonstop0Query[0];

cell = new TableCell();
cell.ID = "cell2";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
cell.Text = nonstop0Query[1];

cell.ID = "cell3";
row.Cells.Add(cell);
cell.Text = nonstop0Query[2];

//Same way can be done for more dataset to bind to row.
```

Comment: still not sure how to do it. can you point me to some sample code?

Comment: hi, i'm having trouble with the line of code:
cell.Text = nonstop0Query[0];

Comment: that is i m just representing the returned property i.e id, name & age. if you get nonstop0query count > 1 then you will have to iterate it else you can just do nonstop0query.ID and so on... this code is just pseudo. :)